# How to make a dictionary in python and save data in a file

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating over grouped items and based on item,user combination I am extracting user features, by using following code:

```
for counter in grouped.iterrows():
    user_id = counter[1]['user_id']
    item_id = counter[1]['item_id']
    career_level = get_value(users, user_id, 'career_level')
    industry_id = get_value(users, user_id, 'industry_id')
    country = get_value(users, user_id, 'country')
    career_level = 'CL_' + str(career_level)
    industry_id = 'IND_' + str(industry_id)
    print(item_id, user_id, country, career_level, industry_id)
```

In output what I got is:

```
5 797978 JO_4092133 ch CL_0 IND_1
12 1524899 JO_524518 JO_2169794 JO_2905196 de CL_2 IND_0
12 2703661 JO_1210814 JO_2573697 de CL_3 IND_0
14 1054241 JO_2804344 JO_1072229 de CL_3 IND_14
14 1297953 JO_3482421 de CL_6 IND_0
14 1548532 JO_425546 de CL_2 IND_0
14 1609264 JO_4438218 JO_1151866 de CL_3 IND_9
```

Now my desired output is something like this:

```
5 797978 JO_4092133 ch CL_0 IND_1

12 1524899 JO_524518 JO_2169794 JO_2905196 de CL_2 IND_0, 2703661 JO_1210814 JO_2573697 de CL_3 IND_0

14 1054241 JO_2804344 JO_1072229 de CL_3 IND_14, 1297953 JO_3482421 de CL_6 IND_0, 1548532 JO_425546 de CL_2 IND_0, 1609264 JO_4438218 JO_1151866 de CL_3 IND_9
```

That means if some user1 has interacted with item1 and another user2 has also interacted with item1, then user1 and user2's features should be in single row.

Could anyone suggest me how could I achieve this goal?

My second question is:
How can I write this data into a file?

I am a beginner to python. I appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: For your second question (as you admit you're a beginner): https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: What is your input? Is `grouped` a pandas dataframe? What does it look like? That would make it easier to reproduce your problem

Comment: @Peter9192 My input is pandas dataframe.  interactions_df = interactions[interactions['interaction_type'].isin([1,2,3])]

grouped = interactions_df.groupby(['item_id', 'user_id']).count().reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

# creating a dataframe
idx = ['one','two','two','two','three','three']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,24).reshape((6,4)), index = idx, columns = list('ABCD'))
df = df.reset_index()

# converting the data frame to a dictionary based on the format desired
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for counter in df.iterrows():
    data_dict[str(counter[1][0])].append(str(list(counter[1][1:]))[1:-1].replace(",",""))

# writing the dictionary to file
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient = 'index')
df2.to_csv('temp.csv', header = False)
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks, this helps